# What is the probability of a specific sequence of 11 digits occurring in a random sequence of one billion digits?

Tags: probability, random, pi

This isn't homework, I'm actually (please don't ask me why) wondering how likely it is that any particular 11-digit telephone number will occur in the first billion digits of pi. My probability course was way too long ago, and the idea of creating a monte carlo simulation to figure this out seems a little extreme!

(And I realize that pi is not a random number, I'm just assuming that the digits are sequenced in a randomlike way.)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the answer is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314740/probability-that-a-random-n-digit-sequence-has-specific-m-digit-subsequence?rq=1

Comment: It depends on the phone number.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: How does it depend on the phone number?

Comment: See my comment under @Avraham's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the simplifying assumption that 11-digit phone numbers can have any digit in any place, it's just under $1\%$ (about $0.9951046\%$).

There are $10^{11}$ possible "phone numbers" only one of which is the "magic" number, so the probability of **not** seeing the phone number for any one 11 digits string is $\frac{10^{11} - 1}{10^{11}}$. However, with one billion digits, there are $10^9 - 11 = 999999989$ places for this string to have to **not** occur. So we get:
$$
\begin{align}
&1 - \left(\frac{10^{11} - 1}{10^{11}}\right)^{999999989}\\
&=\large 1 - e^{999999989\left(\log(10^{11} - 1) - \log(10^{11})\right)}\\
&\approx 1- e^{-0.01000089}\\
&\approx 1-0.99049\\
&\approx 0.009951046
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Do we have to assume that the content of every 11 digit substring of $\pi$ are independent, or does that simply change nothing ?  In fact I'm wondering, can we state $P($number doesn't start at position $i$ AND not at position $i + 1) = P($number doesn't start at position $i)^2$ ?

Comment: Be careful, some strings are more probable than others

Comment: @vonbrand for phone numbers, yes; as random 11-digit numbers from 00000000000 to 999999999999, there are exactly $10^{11}$ of them, as order does matter.

Comment: @Avraham the substring  000 appears more often than 001, as it can overlap itself

Comment: Overlap itself? For a given 11-digit string not to appear in a fixed 11 digits is $\frac{10^{11} - 1}{10^{11}}$. There are 999,999,989 possible starting locations for those strings. What does overlapping have to do with anything? We are not interested in the count of identical phone numbers, but the existence of a particular one, which is 1 - none.

Comment: The expected number of occurrences does not depend on the phone number.  The probability of at least one occurrence does: self-overlapping phone numbers are less likely to occur at all, but more likely to occur multiple times.  For instance, consider the probability of finding "01" vs "11" in a random three-digit binary string.  The former occurs (once) in "010", "011", "101", and "001"; so $p_0=p_1=1/2$ and $p_2=0$.  The latter occurs once in "110" and "011", and twice in "111"; so $p_0=5/8$, $p_1=1/4$, and $p_2=1/8$.

Comment: The point is, as @manuellafond pointed out, that occurrences of the target string at adjacent or nearly-adjacent locations are not independent.  So the probability of non-occurrence at all positions is *not* exactly the probability of non-occurrence at one position raised to the power of the number of positions.

Comment: Please unaccept this answer for now, the comments indicate that it isn't correct and I need to rethink. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is actually fairly complicated, and I would refer you to the article "A unified approach to word occurrence probabilities" ([link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X00001955)) for an exhaustive analysis.  But we can approximate the result more simply.

Note that the expected number of occurrences (counting overlaps) is trivial to obtain: there are $N-n+1$ possible starting positions, and the probability of an occurrence at each such position is $10^{-n}$, so the expected number of occurrences is exactly $(N-n+1)10^{-n}$.  For $N=10^9$ and $n=11$, this is $10^{-2} - 10^{-10} \approx 0.01$.  So we know that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i\cdot p_i = p_1 + 2p_2 + \cdots=p_{\ge 1}+p_{\ge 2}+\cdots=(N-n+1)10^{-n},
$$
where $p_i$ is the probability of exactly $i$ occurrences and $p_{\ge i}$ is the probability of at least $i$ occurrences.  In particular, we have this exact result:
$$
p_0=1-p_{\ge 1}=1-(N-n+1)10^{-n}+p_{\ge 2}+p_{\ge 3}+\cdots.
$$
We see that the likelihood of there being *no* occurrences increases, perhaps surprisingly, along with the likelihood of there being multiple occurrences.  Now, in your case $N\gg n$, so we can largely ignore the existence of one occurrence when looking for another: any pairs are almost certain to be far apart, so the probability of any pairs is about $\frac{1}{2}(0.01)^2$, giving
$$
p_0 \approx 1 - 0.01 + \frac{1}{2}(0.01)^2=0.99005.
$$
However, there are two exceptions arising from self-overlapping phone numbers.  If the phone number consists of a single digit (1-111-111-1111), then given one occurrence, an immediate recurrence has probability $10^{-1}$.  This makes $p_{\ge 2}\approx 10^{-3}$ instead (twenty times larger than usual), hence $p_0\approx 0.991$.  Similarly, if the phone number consists of a repeating pair of digits (1-212-121-2121), then an immediate recurrence has probability $10^{-2}$.  This combines with the (comparable) probability of an independent second occurrence to give $p_{\ge 2}\approx 1.5\times 10^{-4}$ (three times larger than usual), hence $p_0\approx 0.99015$.  (Phone numbers that self-overlap at longer intervals, like 1-213-121-3121, are also slightly less likely to occur, but there the effect is small enough to be ignored.)